# How to test a ReactJS function which uses hooks and does not return JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to get my head around functional testing in React and I've hit a bit of a blocker which I wish someone can shed some light on. Currently, I have a little counter application which has a button component that receives a function and a string as props. that looks like this:

*Button.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export const Button = (props) => {
  const { btnTitle, btnAction } = props

  return (
    <button onClick={btnAction}>{btnTitle}</button>
  )
}

Button.propTypes = {
  btnAction: PropTypes.func,
  btnTitle: PropTypes.string
}
```

I also have a helpers directory that contains my CounterHandler function which receives a number as the counter initial value and can either increase or decrease said initial value. The code looks as follows:

*CounterHandler.js*

```
import React from 'react'

export const CounterHandler = num => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(num)
  const increase = () => setCounter(counter + 1)
  const decrease = () => setCounter(counter - 1)

  return {
    counter,
    increase,
    decrease
  }
}
```

now my App.js which renders the button and the action code looks like this.

*App.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import CounterHandler from './components/button/helpers'
import Button from './components/button'

function App () {
  const counter = CounterHandler(0)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button btnTitle="click to increase" btnAction={counter.increase} />
      <Button btnTitle="click to decrease" btnAction={counter.decrease} />
      <h1>counter: {counter.counter}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

The application works as it's intended. The counter will increase or decrease based on which button was pressed.

Now I'm attempting to write a test for my *CounterHandler.js* function, but unfortunately, I keep hitting a hooks error that does not occur when running the application on my local server.

So far the only test I wanted to try is to get the initial value found in my counter and continue from there. My test looks like this:

*CounterHandler.test.js*

```
import { CounterHandler } from './CounterHandler'

const counter = CounterHandler(0)

describe('Counter state', () => {
  test('test initial state', () => {
    expect(counter.counter).tobe(0)
  })
})
```

and the output I'm getting is:

[image]

Can someone give me some pointers? I would greatly appreciate it.

for a further look into my configs, this is my experimental GitHub account for this project. https://github.com/melvinalmonte/testing-practice

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message is shown, react hooks(`useState` etc..) should be called inside of the react component. But in your test, you called it outside of the react component.

The recommended way to test this case is: Don't test custom hooks directly, test it with react component together.

E.g.
`app.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { CounterHandler } from './counterHandler';

function App() {
  const counter = CounterHandler(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button name="increase" onClick={counter.increase}>
        click to increase
      </button>
      <button name="decrease" onClick={counter.decrease}>
        click to decrease
      </button>
      <h1>counter: {counter.counter}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`counterHandler.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const CounterHandler = (num) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(num);
  const increase = () => setCounter(counter + 1);
  const decrease = () => setCounter(counter - 1);

  return {
    counter,
    increase,
    decrease,
  };
};
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from './app';

describe('60158977', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<App></App>);
  });
  it('should render', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('h1').text()).toBe('counter: 0');
  });

  it('should increase counter', () => {
    wrapper.find('button[name="increase"]').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('h1').text()).toBe('counter: 1');
  });

  it('should decrease counter', () => {
    wrapper.find('button[name="decrease"]').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('h1').text()).toBe('counter: -1');
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60158977/app.test.js
  60158977
    ✓ should render (9ms)
    ✓ should increase counter (3ms)
    ✓ should decrease counter (1ms)

-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 app.js            |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 counterHandler.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.884s, estimated 4s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60158977

Comment: Thanks for your help! This was what I was looking for. Another question, just to make sure I’m understanding this correct. Because we’re not testing plain JS but react itself I would need to test my component not just my individual function right?  I cannot isolate my handler as it can be tested as a whole (almost like integration style).

Comment: I want to know how to test for the object returned by the countHandler hooks. By testing the object, i mean testing the shape and values returned within the object.